# ConfigurationProperties does not bind properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I want to bind my application.properties into a class automatically by using @ConfigurationProperties annotation. First, I tried with @Value annotation and was able to inject property values into class variables. However, @ConfigurationProperties did not inject properties into values.

my application.properties:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=false
my.url=my_url
my.name=muatik
```

application.java

```
package com.muatik;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        final ConfigBinder confs = ctx.getBean(ConfigBinder.class);
        System.out.println(confs.getUrl());
        System.out.println(confs.getName());
    }

}
```

ConfigBinder.java

```
package com.muatik;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;



@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class ConfigBinder {

    @Value("${my.name}")
    private String name;

    private String url; // expected to be filled automatically

    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }
}
```

output:

```
...
2017-01-18 15:19:29.720  INFO 4153 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http)
2017-01-18 15:19:29.724  INFO 4153 --- [           main] com.muatik.Application                   : Started Application in 4.212 seconds (JVM running for 4.937)
null
muatik
```

What is the wrong with this implementation?

**edit and solution**:
possible duplication: [Spring Boot @ConfigurationProperties not retrieving properties from Environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28485442/spring-boot-configurationproperties-not-retrieving-properties-from-environment?rq=1)

I found that I missed the setters in ConfigBinder. After adding them, it works now.

Comment: According to docs @ ConfigurationProperties works only in @ Configuration annotated classes

Comment: I annotated ConfigBinder with `@Configuration` but it still did not work.

Comment: It's the setter for the property you are missing. I also was wondering why my property values are not being filled. If you use the @Value you can keep things private. If you want the prefix thing to work, add just a setter for the property to be set.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to remove @Component from you properties class and add setters because standard bean property binding is used by `@ConfigurationProperties`:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class ConfigBinder {

    private String name;

    private String url; // expected to be filled automatically

    public String getUrl() {
        return this.url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return this.name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
}
```

And add @EnableConfigurationProperties to your main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigBinder.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        final ConfigBinder confs = ctx.getBean(ConfigBinder.class);
        System.out.println(confs.getUrl());
        System.out.println(confs.getName());
    }

}
```

Comment: I've made the changes but the result is same. updated code is here:  https://github.com/muatik/spring-playground/tree/master/spring-profiles-example1

Comment: @Muatik add setters for your fields. They are required, because standard bean property binding is used by `@ConfigurationProperties`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Or use lombok `@Data` to generate all the necessary methods for `ConfigBinder`.

Comment: This is not correct, you don't need to use "@EnableConfigurationProperties", it's a choice : "Enable support for ConfigurationProperties annotated beans. ConfigurationProperties beans can be registered in the standard way (for example using @Bean methods) or, for convenience, can be specified directly on this annotation."

Comment: The minimum is the `setter` method

Comment: So did y'all figure it out? Cause I did all of that and still getting the same issue

Answer (score 11):

The main problem is that you do not have setters. When you put setters to ConfigBuilder works fine. The ConfigBuilder must be like this

```
@Component
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class ConfigBinder {

    private String name;

    private String url;

    // Getters and Setters !!!
}
```

Comment: I am using Kotlin with spring and this was the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

As of spring boot 3 you are no longer forced to use setters to achieve property binding.
If you prefer injecting your properties through the constructor, you can now do so:
(Make sure to remove the `@Component` annotation as described in the accepted answer and that your constructor is *not* annotated with `@Autowired`)

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public class ConfigBinder {

    private final String name;
    private final String url;

    public ConfigBinder(String name, String url) {
        this.name = name;
        this.url = url;
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigBinder.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        final ConfigBinder confs = ctx.getBean(ConfigBinder.class);
        System.out.println(confs.getUrl());
        System.out.println(confs.getName());
    }
}
```

The injection works even when the constructor is private.
If you have more than one constructor, annotate the one you want to be injected with values from properties with `@ConstructorBinding`.

You can even go a step further and use a record instead:

```
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="my")
public record ConfigBinder(String name, String url) {
}
```

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigBinder.class)
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        var ctx = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
        final ConfigBinder confs = ctx.getBean(ConfigBinder.class);
        System.out.println(confs.url());
        System.out.println(confs.name());
    }
}
```