# ConfigurationProperties does not bind properties in combination with an explicit feign configuration class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I want to bind properties from the application.yml automatically by using @ConfigurationProperties on a bean but the properties won't be injected.

My problem seems similar to [ConfigurationProperties does not bind properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719466/configurationproperties-does-not-bind-properties) but the solutions in that post didn't work for me.

My setup is as follows:

application.yml

```
keycloak:
  host: localhost
  port: 8085
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: admin-cli
      username: admin
      password: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://${keycloak.host}:${keycloak.port}/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
```

KeycloakFeignClientConfiguration.java

```
public class KeycloakFeignClientConfiguration {

    @Value("${security.oauth2.client.clientId}")
    private String clientId;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("security.oauth2.client")
    public ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails() {
        // ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails comes from org.springframework.security
        return new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    }

    @Bean
    public RequestInterceptor oauth2FeignRequestInterceptor(ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails) {
        return new OAuth2FeignRequestInterceptor(new DefaultOAuth2ClientContext(), resourceDetails);
    }
}
```

If I set a breakpoint in the oauth2FeignRequestInterceptor-Method and look for resourceDetails-Properties all of them are null. In case of the @Value annotation the value is set correctly.
To add an annotation @Configuration on the KeycloakFeignClientConfiguration-Class makes no difference.

KeycloakProxy.java

```
@FeignClient(name ="noName", url = "http://${keycloak.host}:${keycloak.port}/auth", configuration = KeycloakFeignClientConfiguration.class)
public interface KeycloakProxy {

    // ...some request mappings
}
```

We must specify an explicit configuration class because otherwise the wrong configuration class will be used for this proxy. The project contains multiple feign client configuration classes).

ServiceApplication.java

```
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableTransactionManagement
@SpringBootApplication
public class ServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Validate.notNull(args, "args");
        SpringApplication.run(ServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

Adding @EnableConfigurationProperties to the ServiceApplication makes also no difference. If I add @EnableConfigurationProperties(KeycloakFeignClientConfiguration.class) or @EnableConfigurationProperties(ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails.class) I get an exception which says that the classes have no @ConfigurationProperties.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No ConfigurationProperties annotation found on  'com.gbtec.bic.cloud.tenant.remote.keycloak.KeycloakFeignClientConfiguration'.
```

What works for me is if I move the resourceDetails-Method from KeycloakFeignClientConfiguration to an additional configuration class and annotate these with @Configuration. For example:

```
@Configuration
public class ServiceConfiguration {
    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("security.oauth2.client")
    public ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails resourceDetails() {
        return new ResourceOwnerPasswordResourceDetails();
    }
}
```

This way the bean will be created (in right application context?) and the properties will be injected. Here I will get resourceDetails with the whole configuration inside oauth2FeignRequestInterceptor-Method in KeycloakFeignClientConfiguration.java

I want to avoid to create the additional configuration class to create a resource details bean. Do you have any ideas to solve this problem?

**Edit 23.07.2018**

As requested we created an example project which illustrates the problem: [Link to GitHub-Project](https://github.com/gbtec-ag/configuration-properties-issue)

- To run the test, Docker is required because we use Testcontainers.
- The KeycloakProxy is named (in the test Project) ExampleFeignClient

Comment: What you have described should work without any need to use a separate configuration class. Something that you haven't described must be causing the problem. Can you share a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](/help/mcve) that reproduces it?

Comment: As requested we created an example project which illustrates the problem. See post edit from 23.07 :)

Comment: Ran into this same problem and separated out the config classes and it worked. Not ideal at all and definitely one more broken thing in Spring but it works.

Comment: I have the same problem. It seems FeignConfiguration not working with ConfigurationProperties