# @ConfigurationProperties does not map anything, but using $Value does

Tags: java, spring

I am trying to map file property file into a POJO. If U use `$Value`, it works:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:dashboard.properties"})
public class DashBoardProperties {
    @Value("${dashboard.generate}")
    private boolean generate;
    @Value("${dashboard.output}")
    private String output;
    @Value("${dashboard.input}")
    private String input;

    //getters and setters
}
```

However, when I use `@ConfigurationProperties`, the fields are empty/null:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource({"classpath:dashboard.properties"})
@ConfigurationProperties( prefix = "dashboard")
public class DashBoardProperties {
    private boolean generate;
    private String output;
    private String input;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Why is this happening? I am retrieving the property class (in non-spring managed class) using util class:

```
@Service
public class BeanUtil implements ApplicationContextAware {

    private static ApplicationContext context;

    @Override
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException {
        context = applicationContext;
    }

    /**
     * Use this method to manually autowire Spring Beans into classes that are not managed by Spring.
     *
     * @param beanClass - Class type of the required bean.
     **/
    public static <T> T getBean(Class<T> beanClass) {
        return context.getBean(beanClass);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you `@EnableConfigurationProperties` on Application/Main? And you can remove `@PropertySource`

Comment: i did not, as i do not have main class ( framework ).  I read it is not neccessary to add this annotation if i have it as component

Comment: You can try remove PropertySource and use the @EnableConfigurationProperties on the code where you're calling the library. Make sure you also have the right ComponentScan.

Comment: i tried to add @EnableConfigurationProperties on my context configuration class ( where i have component scan declared) but it thrw error :Loading app context results in java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:

Comment: The flow you're using seems a bit confusing can you improve your question with more information?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ConfigurationProperties does not bind properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41719466/configurationproperties-does-not-bind-properties)

Comment: @pringi i have setters..

Comment: I have the same issue tho there is getter setter and enableConfigureProperitys

Comment: But at least you show us your property file/yaml file